# React Redux child component gets global property set by parent component without passing it in through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Suppose I have a component

```
<Page address=address>
  <Child>
   address
  <Child>
 <deeply nested child>
  <Child>
   address
  <Child>
 </deeply nested child>
</Page>
```

How could I ensure that all my Child components gets the address without passing it in through props everytime

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why would you not pass it as a prop from a controller view?

Comment: just for ease of use I suppose

Comment: I'm no expert, but I do think passing props from a toplevel controllerview is the recommended way. Then again - it's up to you to decide what will be that top level component ;)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by top level controller? In redux, are you referring to the reducer? If so, how would you pass that state to all Childs?

Comment: Take a look here: https://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html ("Presentational and Container Components") :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by telling you that this is a bad idea. Passing props explicitly allows:

- Easily unit testable component
- Allow you to create stateless components
- Allow you to rely on the PureRenderMixin
- Implicit dependencies are a sink hole of maintenance issue and break the idea of react views being stateless

In short, props are great, just use them!

That all being said. If you really need to pass something down without using props. Then you're looking to use [react context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

Context is the mechanism behind react-redux provider (e.g `<Provider store={store}>`)